# QProcess not executing a python script

Tags: python, c++, qt, qtcore, qprocess

I'm trying to execute a process in Qt (in Linux) that executes a python script and I haven't been able to make it work. This is the code:

```
QProcess process;
QString scriptFile = "../../scriptPath/script.py";

QString pyCommand = "\"python " + scriptFile + 
                    " -f " + parameter1 +
                    " -t parameter2" +
                    " -v parameter3" +
                    " -e " + parameter4 + "\"";

printf("PyCommand: %s\n", qStringToStdString(pyCommand).c_str());

process.start ("bash", QStringList () << "-c" << pyCommand);
```

Where `parameter1` and `parameter3` are QStrings that I get from file dialogs (both paths are correct) and `parameter2` and `parameter4` are hardcoded strings (just in case, these strings have characters "-" and "." in them). Function `qStringToStdString` is a function I have created to transform a `QString` to a `std::string` and it works just fine (I already have used it).

PyCommand is printed in the console and looks fine. In fact, if I open a terminal and try to execute `bash -c` followed by what I get in the printf instruction it works. But it doesn't work when I execute the Qt application.

Can someone help me out here? Something I'm missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code is ignoring how the API was designed to work. You should use either of the alternatives presented below. Using the `python` interpreter explicitly depends on whether you use the shebang properly in your python script. I have just let it in for reference, but you can easily get rid of that. It is not the main point of your issue in here.

#### First alternative (`QStringList` based)

```
QProcess process;
QString scriptFile =  QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "../../scriptPath/script.py";

QStringList pythonCommandArguments = QStringList() << scriptFile
    << "-f " << parameter1 << "-t" <<  parameter2 << "-v"
    <<  parameter3 << "-e" << parameter4;

printf("PyCommand: %s\n", qStringToStdString(pythonCommandArguments.join(' ')).c_str());

process.start ("python", pythonCommandArguments);
```

#### Second alternative (`QString` based)

```
QProcess process;
QString scriptFile =  QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "../../scriptPath/script.py";

QString pythonCommand = "python " + scriptFile + 
                    " -f " + parameter1 +
                    " -t parameter2" +
                    " -v parameter3" +
                    " -e " + parameter4;

printf("PyCommand: %s\n", qStringToStdString(pythonCommand).c_str());

process.start (pythonCommand);
```

Here you can find the proper method signatures for both ways:

- `void QProcess::start(const QString & program, const QStringList & arguments, OpenMode mode = ReadWrite)`

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#start

- `void QProcess::start(const QString & command, OpenMode mode = ReadWrite)`

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#start-3

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `QStringList()` for command line parameter.

Your `pyCommand` must be `QStringList`.

Something like this:

```
QStringList pyCommand;
pyCommand << "-f" << parameter1 <<
                "-t" << parameter2 <<
                "-v" << parameter3 <<
                "-e" << parameter4;

process.start(scriptFile, pyCommand);
```

See the docs: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#start

Answer (score 1):

So at the end I got it working. As Laszlo commented out, the way it should be executed is starting a process with `python` and pass all the arguments as a `QStringList`. That's what I tried at the beginning and it wasn't working at all. So I looked for information on the internet and I saw that many people were executing a `bash` process and then they were passing a string with the python command instead of doing it as I was. I tried to do it that way but it wasn't working either...

The solution? Well, I've done what I should have done before asking the question here. I connected the most important signals of the process (started, finished and error) with some simple methods that wrote output. At the end I found out that python was returning `2` (No such file or directory) as the `exitCode`.

It seems that the application wasn't taking the executable path as the root path and therefore the path I was referring to (`"../../scriptPath/script.py"`) didn't exist. In order to get the proper binary path I use now `QDir::currentPath() + "/scriptPath/script.py"`.

Comment: Uh, no, use  QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() instead of QDir::currentPath() as I mentioned in my post. I would suggest to revisit my answer again. It is probably not the best answer to accept, but I will leave it with you.